# return new set for one class

Tags: java, hashset

I ran into a problem with Java recently. I have a HashSet `hashSet` with a superclass 'Foo'. This set is filled with subclasses of `foo` : `bar` and `dop`. How do I return a new HashSet filled with values only with values of class `bar` or `dop`?

I tried the following:

```
public Set<Foo> getObjectsFromClass(Foo foo) {
    Set<Foo> objectsFromClass = new HashSet<>();
        for (Foo value: hashSet) {
            if ((value instanceof Bar) && (foo instanceof Bar))
                objectsFromClass.add(value);
            if ((value instanceof Dop) && (foo instanceof Dop))
                objectsFromClass.add(value);
        }
    }
    return objectsFromClass;
}
```

But the problem is I have to give up an argument with an object, while I just want to specify the class. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want to pass in the class (rather than an instance of the class) and use [`Class.isInstance`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isInstance-java.lang.Object-):

```
public Set<Foo> getObjectsFromClass(Class<? extends Foo> clazz) {
    Set<Foo> objectsFromClass = new HashSet<>();
    for (Foo value: hashSet) {
        if (clazz.isInstance(value)) {
            objectsFromClass.add(value);
        }
    }
    return objectsFromClass;
}
```

Then call it with:

```
Set<Foo> x = getObjectsFromClass(Dop.class);
```

As a bonus, the constraint on the parameter means that if you try to do something silly, it won't compile:

```
Set<Foo> x = getObjectsFromClass(String.class); // Error
```

If you need to change the return type to reflect the subtype as well, you can make the method generic:

```
static <T extends Foo> Set<T> getObjectsFromClass(Class<T> clazz) {
    Set<T> objectsFromClass = new HashSet<>();
    for (Foo value: hashSet) {
        if (clazz.isInstance(value)) {
            objectsFromClass.add(clazz.cast(value));
        }
    }
    return objectsFromClass;
}
```

Then you can use:

```
Set<Dop> dops = getObjectsFromClass(Dop.class);
```

Comment: Why can't I construct the set:

    `Set<Dop> x = getObjectsFromClass(Dop.class);`

Comment: @username_HI: Because you declared that the method would return a `Set<Foo>`. I can change the answer to do that if you want though... (Done now.)